# Foundation 6 - Panini - #if production flag?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm creating a website using Foundation 6 (based on the Zurb template)
I want to use some HTML (namely, Google Analytics) that's meant to be added only if the gulp's production flag is set.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Not [foundation]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `gulp-string-replace` to do things like this. I set a unique string in the HTML such as `<!-- {{{GA_CODE}}} -->` and have gulp replace the string if the production flag is set.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-string-replace

You could use this with something like `gulp-if`

https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if